# Nuxt.js api resquest on server-side returning error net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: api, axios, nuxt.js, server-side

I need to make an application (nuxt) that will be located in a DMZ of my infrastructure, while my API will be on the LAN. When testing the application the error below occurs, saying that the client was unable to resolve the name, but nuxt would not request the server-side? If it is done on the server-side, why does the client need a route to my API server? I put the link on GitHub in the project I used as an example.

```
b19210e.js:1 GET https://api02.lohr.com.br/cp/product-info?code=1822X net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

https://github.com/ErikCH/NuxtiTunesSearch